# Ambiguous type variable when wrapping typeclass function in existential

Tags: haskell, typeclass, existential-type

I'm using a typed tagless final encoding in an interpreter. Unfortunately, I'm having issues with the typechecking phase. The minimal testcase is as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ExistentialQuantification, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
class Program repr where
    ...
    intro1 :: repr a (a, ())
    ...

data DynTerm repr = forall x y. (Typeable x, Typeable y) => DynTerm (repr x y)

ghci> DynTerm intro1
```

This produces the following error:

```
Could not deduce (Typeable x0) arising from a use of `DynTerm'
from the context (Program repr)
  bound by the inferred type of it :: Program repr => DynTerm repr
  at <interactive>:3:1-14
The type variable `x0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Typeable Void -- Defined in `Data.Void'
  instance [overlap ok] Typeable ()
    -- Defined in `Data.Typeable.Internal'
  instance [overlap ok] Typeable Bool
    -- Defined in `Data.Typeable.Internal'
  ...plus 25 others
In the expression: DynTerm intro1
In an equation for `it': it = DynTerm intro1
```

I expected the compiler to reason as follows:

- Attempt to unify a with x.
- Add Typeable a to the list of constraints (I can manually add this through a type annotation, which makes no difference).
- Succeed.
- Attempt to unify (a, ()) with y.
- Note that since we're assuming Typeable a, Typeable (a, ()) also holds.
- Succeed.

However, it seems to be failing on unifying x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When constructing a value of type `DynTerm` using the `DynTerm` constructor, GHC has to know the concrete types `x` and `y` in order to decide which `Typeable` dictionaries should be packed in. In your test expression, you are not providing sufficient type information to determine concrete types, therefore you get an error that certain type variables are ambiguous. It works if you specifically pick a concrete `Typeable` type.

Example (with `ScopedTypeVariables`):

```
test :: forall repr. Program repr => DynTerm repr
test = DynTerm (intro1 :: repr Int (Int, ()))
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Do you know if there is a way to avoid the requirement that the types be concrete? At this point in the code, I wouldn't actually know what the final type of a would be.

Comment: I don't understand your follow-up question. What do you actually want to do with this?

Comment: It's part of an interpreter, in particular the conversion from an untyped expression to a typed one. "repr a b" represents a function from a to b (the repr part is to do with the TTF encoding I'm using). The problem is when I'm converting the body of a polymorphic function, there is no valid concrete type. I was sort of hoping for some way that GHC could track partial dictionaries, and at the end cast the entire program to the appropriate type, and have GHC fill in the holes. That said, I've just remembered that cast is implemented with unsafeCoerce, so that couldn't possibly work.

Comment: In the end, I solved my actual problem through the use of the rank1dynamic package.

Answer (score 2):

As kosmikus noted, `ExistentialQuantification` means that you will abstract over the type variable, but the implementer of your data type must pick a single, monomorphic type:

> [When a value of this type is constructed, s will be instantiated to some concrete type. When such a value is analysed, s is abstract.](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/ExistentialQuantification)

Consider the following:

```
data D = forall a . Show a => D (a -> String) 
-- test0 = D show -- Invalid!
test1 = D (show :: () -> String)

data E = E (forall a . Show a => a -> String)
test2 = E show -- Invalid!
-- test3 = E (show :: () -> String)
```

So perhaps you want

```
data DynTerm repr = DynTerm (forall x y. (Typeable x, Typeable y) => repr x y)
```

But this still won't work with `intro1` - it is not sufficiently polymorphic (`(a,())` is more specific than `x`). If you had `intro2 :: Program repr => repr x y` you could write `DynTerm intro2`.